# List items overlaps each other

Tags: android, android-layout

i like to implement a layout for a listview  like this:
[image]

Any idea how i can implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a couple of ways, but I think the most convenient way is to create two `9-patch` background images so that you can define which sides should scale in what way. (Check [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for information about 9-patch)

Make sure that the background image has a transparent part, where you want the one list item to overlap with the other, and set the `layout_marginTop` of the second item negative on an amount that gives you the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

This Approach must Help,Using two Different View and Displaying One at one Time based on Position
[image]

Comment: Sorry but i can't modify the UI.

Answer (score 0):

To implement listView elements as the screenshot, you need to have a CustomListViewAdapter (extends ArrayAdapter ) and in your CustomListViewAdapter class you need to specify in the method getView() the background to use in each element as below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

    if ((position % 2) == 0) {
        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trapeze_down);
    } else {
        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trapeze_up);
    }
    rowView.refreshDrawableState();
    return rowView;
}
```

Note: 
* rowLayout represent the layout of an element in the listView
* trapeze_down and trapeze_up are two png images representing the trapeze  form you want to have in background
* when you create your list view, don't forget to specify : 
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
*And finally you just set the adapter to your listView